# CountDownTimer в Service не работает во второй раз

Tags: android

здраствуйте , я запускаю первый раз `Service` но во второй раз когда я запускаю `Service` то ничего не происходит

```
         public static void readyToGame() {
                    sActivity.startService(new Intent(sActivity.getApplicationContext(), ServiceTimer.class));
                    sActivity.registerReceiver(br, new IntentFilter(ServiceTimer.COUNTDOWN_BR));
                }

          private static void endTimerRun() {
                sActivity.unregisterReceiver(br);
                sActivity.stopService(new Intent(sActivity.getApplicationContext(), LoadingFragmentController.class));
            }

   private static BroadcastReceiver br = new BroadcastReceiver() {
        @Override
        public void onReceive(Context context, Intent intent) {
            updateGUI(intent); 
        }
    };

    public class ServiceTimer extends Service {

        private final static String TAG = "BroadcastService";

        public static final String COUNTDOWN_BR = "controller.LoadingFragmentController";
        Intent bi = new Intent(COUNTDOWN_BR);

        CountDownTimer cdt = null;

        @Override
        public void onCreate() {
            super.onCreate();

            Log.i(TAG, "Starting timer...");

            cdt = new CountDownTimer(15000, 1000) {
                @Override
                public void onTick(long millisUntilFinished) {

                    Log.i(TAG, "Countdown seconds remaining: " + (int)millisUntilFinished / 1000);
                    bi.putExtra("countdown", millisUntilFinished);
                    sendBroadcast(bi);
                }

                @Override
                public void onFinish() {
                    Log.i(TAG, "Timer finished");
                    LoadingFragmentController.endGame();
                }
            };

            cdt.start();
        }

        @Override
        public void onDestroy() {

            cdt.cancel();
            Log.i(TAG, "Timer cancelled");
            super.onDestroy();
        }

        @Override
        public int onStartCommand(Intent intent, int flags, int startId) {
            return super.onStartCommand(intent, flags, startId);
        }

        @Override
        public IBinder onBind(Intent arg0) {
            return null;
        }
    }
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

onCreate сервиса срабатывает только при его создании.

При следующих вызовах startService,  если сервис не был остановлен, будет вызван метод onStartCommand.
Именно туда и перенесите запуск таймера.